# Is there a way to completely disable gdb output?

Tags: c++, gdb, reverse-engineering, exploit

I have a C++ program `a` which has a `win` function, which is never being called.
I can call it with gdb, by simply executing `jump *win`.
The problem is, I'm trying to automate this process, with a one liner:
`gdb -q a -ex "break *main" -ex "run" -ex "jump *(_Z3winv)"`
Is there a way to see *only* the output from the program itself, without this:

```
inxane@root:~/mysecretfolder$ gdb -q a -ex "break *main" -ex "run" -ex "jump *(_Z3winv)"

warning: /mysecretfolder/pwndbg/gdbinit.py: No such file or directory
Reading symbols from a...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8e9
Starting program: /mysecretfolder/a 

Breakpoint 1, 0x00005555555548e9 in main ()
Continuing at 0x5555555548ba.
You won!
[Inferior 1 (process 15866) exited with code 040]
```

(i just want this)

```
You won!
```

If it's necessary, here is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void win()
{
    cout << "You won!" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "You failed!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean besides the obvious answer to not run in `gdb` at all? What is the problem you have with the GDB output? Why do you want to inhibit it? What problem will that solve?

Comment: I'm trying to run the `win` function which is not being called in the program itself. It's for reverse engineering practice. The problem is I don't want the gdb output, just the program's output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the option `-batch-silent` to your gdb command

see documentation '[gdb documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options)'